# Setting the date format in the database

Tags: mysql

When I'm working locally, have to perform the update routine as well:

"update products set prodataval = str_to_date('26/12/2015','%e/%c/%Y')
where procod = 10".

When I'm on the web update is as follows:

"update products set prodataval = str_to_date('12/26/2015','%e/%c/%Y')
where procod = 10".

I want to know if there is any way to get the databases on the same date format so I do not get testing whether I am on the web or locally.

Comment: If you're storing dates using the built-in `date` or `datetime` type then any specific "date format" simply does not apply because internally dates are stored as integers, you only need to worry about formatting issues at the presentation/view layer of your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FWIW You can always use ISO-8061 (`yyyy-MM-dd`) in your date-strings and MySQL will read it unambiguously:

```
UPDATE Products SET prodataval = '2015-12-16' WHERE procod = 10
```